# attempting to purchase 16.04 USB stick

Tags: usb

I am going around in circles attempting to purchase 16.04 on a USB stick from the canonical store. Try to check out, I have to log in. 
I log in correctly, takes me to a 'new account' page. Says if you already have account, click here. When I do that I go straight back to 'new account' page. If I fill that in, it tells me I'm already registered and to log in. When I log in it takes me straight to 'new account' page.
I don't want to download 16.04, I want the 'dinky' USB stick. 
How hard should a purchase be?
Where am I going wrong? (already using 12.04)

Comment: There's a contact form on the page, try sending canonical a message. If there is a problem on the website side of things, they probably should know about it. Link: https://shop.canonical.com/contact_us.php

Comment: Hello, yes, I have contacted them, awaiting reply.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Canonical's store, not Ubuntu, and only Canonical can answer it.

Comment: Fine by me, I have given up with the Canonical store and Ubuntu One. I shall stick to 12.04. Thanks for the advice.